# APEX Transaction's count

Tags: apex, dml

Let's we have some class

```
public class FooTest {
public void goAhead() {
    someOne();
}
private void someOne() {
    /// awesome DML
    for(integer i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
        anotherOne();
    }
}
private void anotherOne() {
    /// awesome DML here   }}
```

How many transactions we have in this case : one or eleven when we call goAhead() method?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have *n* DML operations in one transaction; remember that the scope of a transaction is the session/request - if an exception is thrown and not caught the entire set of interactions with the DB will be discarded (except for those related to Platform Events which are outside the session's transaction). See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm) for details.

From what I have seen, the only way an Apex call forms a new transaction is when it is some form of asynchronous execution - e.g. a future method call, a queueable or schedule execute or the calls to start, execute and finish in a batchable. Plain old Apex method calls are otherwise simply part of the existing session/request.

I was even surprised to read the documentation suggesting that a trigger invocation is a transaction scope; from experience I would say all trigger invocations are a part of the current (request/session) scope.

Comment: The boundary of a transaction can be a trigger, a class method, an anonymous block of code, a Visualforce page, or a custom Web service method. (from documentation). I call 10 class methods - that is my misunderstanding - I if call methods with DML operations from another method - why we have only one transaction?

Comment: So, if we hawe for example Footest ft = new Footest();
ft.goAhead();
ft.goAhead(); so it will be 2 transactions with n DML opertaions in each?

Comment: I have never seen a transaction scoped to an Apex method call - I think this reference in the documentation is incorrect or at least meant an Apex method call that is a future method, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A transaction starts with a request and ends with the end of that request. Request can be made by API Calls, Clicking a button, a future method call, Schedulers, etc.
You can think like this, scope begins when a block of codes gets executed and then finish.

For example, when a visualforce page loads, it actually calls the constructor of the controller. It is a transaction. And there is a button on that page. When you click on the button, some codes get executed. That is another transaction.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction starts when a request is made (API call, UI edit, Visualforce button click, etc) ,and ends when that request ends either successfully, or in a fatal error. Governor limits apply to each transaction.

A DML statement is a single operation. The number of operations is limited per transaction. Refer to the documentation for more information.

Generally speaking, at the moment, you get 150 operations per transaction. You can check your limits and current usage with the Limits class.